For any number field $K$, only finitely many primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ are ramified in $\mathcal{O}_K$.
I am trying to prove this:
Show that for any number field $K$, only finitely many primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ are ramified in $\mathcal{O}_K$. See the definition below:
Definition: Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers in a number field $K$. Given a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, consider the ideal factorization $(p) = \mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_n^{e_n}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, with distinct prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i \neq \mathfrak{p}_j$ for all $i \neq j$. We say that $p$ is ramified in $\mathcal{O}_K$ if any of the $e_i > 1$, otherwise $p$ is unramified.
Hint: A polynomial $f$ has a double root if and only if $f$ and $f'$ share a common factor.
My try:
I am supposed to use the Dedekind-Kummer theorem. Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a number field, where $\alpha$ is a primitive element, meaning that $K$ is generated over $\mathbb{Q}$ by a single element $\alpha$. Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.
From the Dedekind-Kummer theorem, a prime $p$ ramifies in $\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if the polynomial $f(x)$ has a double root modulo $p$. This happens if and only if $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ have a common factor modulo $p$, as the hint suggests (although the hint was not given for polynomials modulo something, so I am not sure this is valid either).
I am stuck at this point, what how do I relate this to finitely many primes being ramified?



The cleanest way I know how to do it is with the discriminant.  If you take a degree $n$ polynomial $h(X)$ with coefficients in a field $k$, and look at the roots $r_1, r_2, ... , r_n$ of $h$ in an algebraic closure of $k$, the discriminant of $h$ is defined to be
$$\prod\limits_{i \neq j} (r_i - r_j).$$
It is an element of $k$, and is zero if and only if $h$ has a repeated root.
The discriminant $\Delta$ of your polynomial $f$ is a nonzero rational number which lies in $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ for all but finitely many primes $p$.  The discriminant is well behaved with respect to reduction modulo $p$ (that is, if the discriminant lies in $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$, then the image of the discriminant in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the discriminant of the polynomial $f \pmod{p}$ in $\mathbb F_p[X]$).
Therefore, for all but finitely many primes $p$, we have that $p$ is ramified if and only if $f(X) \pmod{p}$ has a multiple root in $\overline{F_p}$, if and only if $\Delta \pmod{p}$ is zero, if and only if $p$ divides $\Delta$.  Since only finitely many primes can divide $\Delta$, this proves that at most finitely many primes can be ramified.

Could you elaborate on those 2 facts about the discriminant? Maybe a link to a proof?

Also how are the hypothesis of Dedekind-Kumer satisfied?

Is $Z_p$ the same as $Z_{(p) } $?

No, $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb Z$ at $p$, it consists of all rational numbers whose denominator is not divisible by $p$.  If you complete this ring at $p$, you get $\mathbb Z_p$.

what do you mean with the discriminant of the polynomial? I know it only for a quadratic polynomial (b^2-4ac in ax^2+bx+c=0). The only discriminat I have used in my algebraic numbers course is the discriminant of a basis of a number field, which is the square of the determinant of the matrix involving the images of the basis elements via de embeddings. Is this something else?

I have  a theorem in my notes" The discriminant of any basis of a number feld K is a non-zero rational number", but I don't know how to relate it with the discriminant of a polynomial

The ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ of $K$ is a finitely generated additive abelian group.  If $\mathcal O_K = \mathbb Z[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha \in K$ with minimal polynomial $f$, then the discriminant of any basis of $\mathcal O_K$ is the same as the discriminant of $f$.
